# How Does $\frac{1+\sin(x)}{x}=1 + \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I am asking this because I have faced a (limits) question where, in order to solve the equation, I had to do the following steps:

[image]

I am not sure how the second step went from having a denominator of  $\frac{1+\sin(x)}{x}$ to having a denominator of $1 + \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ in the third step. Can anyone please help explain how this is possible, to me?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There was an error in the very first step.   The author intended to divide numerator and denominator by $x$ but wrote a $1$ where an $x$ was intended in the denominator.  The second error (that you pointed out) actually corrects the first.

Comment: I think it falls in the category of typo, at least that's what I call it when I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there was a typo, but it is earlier than the step that you pointed out. Instead of $$\frac{1+\sin(x)}{x}$$ it should have been $$\frac{x+\sin(x)}{x}$$

Answer (score 4):

There are two cancelling errors in that graphic: from the first step to the second, and the second to the third. You saw only the second error. The sequence of equations should begin

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x+\sin(x)}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}x}{\frac{x+\sin(x)}x}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin(x)}x}{1+\frac{\sin(x)}x}$$

The probable cause is a typographic error in the second step, typing a $1$ rather than an $x$.